# De-dupe NSArray of NSDictionaries based on specific keys

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, deduplication

I am attempting to de-dupe an NSArray of NSDictionaries based on specific keys in the dictionaries. What I have looks something like this:

```
NSDictionary *person1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"John", @"firstName", @"Smith", "lastName", @"7898", @"employeeID"];
NSDictionary *person2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Eric", @"firstName", @"Johnson", "lastName", @"1718" @"employeeID"];
NSDictionary *person3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"John", @"firstName", @"Smith", "lastName", @"1153", @"employeeID"];

NSMutableArray *personArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:person1, person2, person3, nil];

// insert some code to de-dupe personArray based SOLELY on the firstName and lastName keys
```

Notice how there are two employees with the same name but different ID's. What I would like to do is just get back a new array with only person1 and person2, since person3 has the same data - I just don't care about the "employeeID" value in this particular problem.

Any ideas? Thanks!

-Matt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a Person class which inherits from NSDictionary and implement isEqual: ignoring the ID key, cast your dictionaries to this class, then create an NSSet from your Person objects.

Answer (score 0):

In this very case I would create a temporary NSMutableDictionary and add each personX dictionary as object and its "firstName"'s value as key. This way, a personX dictionary will be replaced if another personX with the same name is added to the temporary. Then get the array from the temporary dictionary with *-allValues*.

Comment: I appreciate your fast response! I think this would work well in this case, the only problem, which I forgot to specify is that I am dealing with many thousands of said person objects. Your method works, though I am not certain how scalable it is.

Comment: I may be wrong, but it is understood by me that NSDictionary behave most of the time as hash map, with amortized insertion time of O(1). Initialize the dictionary with with a capacity proportional with the expected number of unique entry to prevent eccessive rehashing and test it. Memory shouldn't be a problem either, because what you insert is actually a reference.

If you have lots of entries and you keep retrieving and manipulating them, maybe Core Data will suit your needs better.